# How to create trainable model inside of recurrent construction in python keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, ocr, recurrent-neural-network

I have an idea of NN, the first step is to get a vector, describing common features of images of the same symbol. So I need a recurrent layer, that has a model for detecting image features inside, something with Conv2D and MaxPool2D (instead of usual Dense in SimpleRNN).

I tried to create my own class of RNNCell, describing this logic, but I suspect models inside are not training (accuracy of the whole model is very low, other steps of the model are obvious and I'm sure they work properly), in model.summary() layers of the RNNCell are also not mentioned. Maybe I need to somehow give information that those layers are trainable?

Class of RNNCell:

```
class ArbitraryRNNCell(keras.layers.AbstractRNNCell):
    def __init__(self, units, forward_model, backward_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.forward_model = forward_model
        self.backward_model = backward_model
        self.units = units

    @property
    def state_size(self):
        return self.units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        current_output = self.forward_model(inputs + self.backward_model(prev_output))
        return current_output, current_output
```

Place in full model initializiation, where class above is used:

```
class_feature_rnn = RNN(
        ArbitraryRNNCell(
             64,
             Sequential([Conv2D(32, 3, input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation="relu"),
                         MaxPool2D(2),
                         Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu"),
                         MaxPool2D(2),
                         Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu"),
                         Flatten(),
                         Dense(64, activation="relu")]),
             Sequential([Dense(784, input_shape=(64,), activation="relu"),
                         Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1))])
        ),
        name="ClassFeaturesRNN"
    )
...
ind_feature = class_feature_rnn(ind_input)
class_features = [class_feature_rnn(class_input) for class_input in class_inputs]
```